# Why are my divs in my NextJS website not rendered when I scroll to them and they disappear when I scroll past them?

Tags: next.js, scroll, rendering

I'm using NextJS and I'm building a website where you can see information on a user in a card. Within this card is more cards with information like their bio and answers to questions.

The issue is that when I scroll through this profile card, The other items aren't rendered and after they render, the disappear once they are off screen so it has to rerender. This isn't ideal because I have to wait for it to render.

Think if you were scrolling through tinder but every new block of information was not rendered.

I tried looking into Lazy loading and messing with the server side rendering using next Dynamic, but it had no effect. Not sure what to do from here.

Heres an image: only the visible part of the card renders:
[Image Of Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfPzF.png)

```
            <div className={styles.CardContainer}>   
                <div className={styles.bioCard}>
                    <div className={styles.titles} >
                        <h3>Bio</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div className={styles.bioTextCard}>
                    
                    </div>
                </div>
                
            </div>

            {/* Goals */}
            <div className={styles.CardContainer}>   
                <div className={styles.bioCard}>
                    <div className={styles.titles} >
                        <h3>Bio</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div className={styles.bioTextCard}>
                    
                    </div>
                </div>
                
            </div>

       
            <div className={styles.CardContainer}>   
                <div className={styles.bioCard}>
                    <div className={styles.titles} >
                        <h3>Bio</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div className={styles.bioTextCard}>
                    
                    </div>
                </div>
                
            </div>

  
            <div className={styles.CardContainer}>   
                <div className={styles.bioCard}>
                    <div className={styles.titles} >
                        <h3>Bio</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div className={styles.bioTextCard}>
                    
                    </div>
                </div>
                
            </div>
```

Comment: There are not enough info to find your problem you cant write good questions following this guide https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . You can also look at this, maybe you find a fix to your problem https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out after a grueling search. Very frustrating but it wasn't any of the issues I thought. It was because I was using this:

```
/* backdrop-filter: blur(30px); */
```

in each card, so it was computationally expensive to render the blur on the background. Therefore it took a while to load. Also the background color was changing at every scroll so I assume that added complexity as well